# How do i compare browser url query string with another on in php or joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, url, joomla2.5

Hi I am trying to execute some code if browser URL or query string is same as with another query string but failed to do that... so please help me how can i do that.

```
<?php
     $pageURL=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
     $pageURL2="option=Some_Option&view=SomeView&task=SomeTask&addrtype=SomeAddType";

     if($pageURL == $pageURL2)
     {
       // Some Code if and only if condition is true (both variable match)
     }
     else
     {
       // Some Code
     }
?>
```

By above mentioned code i am trying to achieve some execution of some code but failed at comparison or don't know what happen at comparison though it execute only if part every time and condition done always true.. Guide me to solve this.

I already use preg_match, preg_match_all, == , === but not able to find the solution.

Comment: what is in $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?

Comment: try - echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];  after $pageURL=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; and let us know what you see...

Comment: @Mahmood Rehman and Potheek i tried that and in Query_String i am getting same as in pageURL2 if page is same and i will get different query string if page is different than pageURL2

Comment: @AnandMehta if you got same string than this works for me $pageURL="option=Some_Option&view=SomeView&task=SomeTask&addrtype=SomeAddType";
       $pageURL2="option=Some_Option&view=SomeView&task=SomeTask&addrtype=SomeAddType";
       if($pageURL == $pageURL2)
       {
        echo "matched";
       }else{ echo "not matched";}

Comment: @Mahmood Rehman... that is what not done actually. I also thought that it should be work as you mentioned in your last comment, but it is not working when i use strcamp function it is give always -1 as a output it mean condition is false in both same url. so now i am thinking to use $_GET and fetch value of option, view, task and addrtype and compare it..... Like if($_GET['option']== 'some_option' && .... so on.... 
Let me see, is it worked or not? ... And thanks for your valuable reply and comments....

Comment: @AnandMehta than try something like this $pageURL=explode("&","$url");
       $pageURL2=explode("&","option=...");
       foreach ($pageURL as $key => $value) {
        if($pageURL[$key] == $pageURL2[$key]){
         
         echo "  matched <br />";
        }else{ echo "not matched";}
       }

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if i have got your question correctly but as far as i have understood i think below code is what you want.

```
<?PHP
  $a="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $b=strpos($a,"?");
  $pageURL=substr($a, $b);      
  $pageURL2="String to match";
       if($pageURL == $pageURL2)
 {
   // Some Code if and only if condition is true (both variable match)
 }
 else
 {
   // Some Code
 }
?>
```

Comment: I want to compare only query string not whole URL if possible.... eg. www.address.index.php?...... query string will be after ?